# Why do variables live longer (have bigger scopes) in Python than in C?

Tags: python, c, scope

Python code:

```
for i in xrange(10):
    for j in xrange(5):
        pass

# The for-loop ends, but i,j still live on
print i,j  # 9, 4
```

C code:

```
for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
    for(int =0; j<=5; j++)
        ;

// The for-loop ends, so i,j can't be accessed, right?
printf("%d, %d", i, j);  // won't compile
```

So, variables in Python will live on even after the `for` loop ends?

Comment: I think the code you are not equivalent. I am not familiar with Python, but if `i` is sthg declared already in python than it is outside `for`, whereas in C, the `i` is local to the for loop.

Comment: The equivalent C code should declare i and j outside the for loops (int i,j ;) then simply assign them in the for loops.

Comment: @Joe I think you mean _could_, not _should_. The point is in Python, you _can't_ declare a variable local to the scope of the loop.

Comment: @Ankit You don't declare variables in Python, so no, that `i` doesn't have to exist prior to its use in the loop.

Comment: On a side note, if it is convenient for your code, you can explicitly delete the variables in Python after the loop, with a `del i, j` statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only functions, modules, and the bodies of class definitions delineate scopes in Python. Other control structures don't.

Some basic information about this is in the [Python Scopes and Namespaces](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) section of the Classes page of the Python Tutorial. One important part:

> Although scopes are determined statically, they are used dynamically. At any time during execution, there are at least three nested scopes whose namespaces are directly accessible:
>
> - the innermost scope, which is searched first, contains the local names
> - the scopes of any enclosing functions, which are searched starting with the nearest enclosing scope, contains non-local, but also non-global names
> - the next-to-last scope contains the current module’s global names
> - the outermost scope (searched last) is the namespace containing built-in names

Comment: Yes, the legb rule, also from the book "Learning Python": http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=1HxWGezDZcgC&pg=PA412&lpg=PA412&dq=python+LGB+scope&source=bl&ots=LjHh-Mfbr0&sig=JKatyA0rvni3wkjBRSN99iDyS5w&hl=en&sa=X&ei=i26LT8r-EIiyiQfE2N2xBg&redir_esc=y&hl=zh-CN&sourceid=cndr#v=onepage&q=python%20LGB%20scope&f=false

Comment: @WooParadog That link doesn't work for me 
(no words display in the book), plus it's not in English. [Here is the link at books.google.com](http://books.google.com/books?id=1HxWGezDZcgC&pg=PA412&lpg=PA412&dq=python+LGB+scope#v=onepage&q=python%20LGB%20scope&f=false)